# is this XOR cryptography secure?

Tags: cryptography, xor, sha512

can somebody explain this algorithm is secure or not? is there attack to break that? this algorithm uses common XOR cryptography but has some differences:

M(1) = key XOR Message(1)
M(2) = h(key) XOR Message(2)
M(3) = h(h(key)) XOR Message(3)
and so on

Notes:

1. M(i) is ciphered text
2. Message(i) is message that we are going to cipher it
3. key and Message(i) have the same lengths**
4. attacker just has the ciphered text and knows key making scheme(continues hashing) and XOR cryptography
5. hash algorithm is SHA-512

Comment: You might also try asking at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please don't crosspost on security.SE or crypto.SE. I've flagged it for migration, but I wouldn't be surprised if it gets closed instead.

Comment: Why do you invent your own crypto? There are plenty of existing stream ciphers. No reason to invent your own bad one.

Comment: i have to invent new crypto algorithm, this is just a little piece of my work, for gaining security i answer this question. if attacker knows the plain-text he/she may also attack to symmetric crypto. in my idea this isn't good idea(attacker khnow plain-text),please give me another reason.tnx

Comment: @oMiD You did not explain why you have to *invent* crypto, instead of using well known and reviewed modes of encryption.

Comment: This is an obviously silly algorithm. There are so many trivial changes that significantly improve its security properties that pretty much all you can do is laugh at it. For example, `M(x) = h(key+x) XOR Message(x)` adds one extra hash total and improves the security dramatically.

Comment: to all of my friends, i want to add some complexity to key, because xor crypto. is strong when key has randomness and same lenght with message

Comment: Then at least use the algorithm David and I suggested, it's much better, and equally fast. But it still suffers from the same problem as all similar constructions: You must not reuse a key, ever. (or you need to introduce a nonce).

Comment: ok, tnx to David and CodeInChaos

Comment: Similar questions were already asked on Cryptography Stack Exchange before: [A simple block cipher based on the SHA-256 hash function](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1703/58) and [Is it feasible to build a stream cipher from a cryptographic hash function?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48/58). The answer is also about the same as the one given by CodeInChaos here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Studying encryption algorithms is great fun.  Just remember you are playing, not producing anything serious.  As long as you are only keeping things like your personal diary (or maybe even passwords) encrypted and you keep the data secure, you will probably be fine.  This kind of counts as security through obscurity.  I would not recommend encrypting mass quantities of data that you *REALLY* need to keep private or anything that is available and of interest to the outside world, however.

---

In this case, if your message is shorter than the key size and hash block size and the key is single use and random, you are effectively using a one-use pad so everything in swell.   Provided your random number key generation is perfect, you have an unbreakable encryption mechanism.  As you add each block to the message, you are effectively calculating new keys using SHA-512, not adding any particular value.  If an attacker can assume the message consists of printable text and if the length of the message is long or the key is used repeatedly, it should would not be too difficult to find the original key.

It would be more effective to calculate:

```
M(1)=h(N + key) XOR Message(1)
M(2)=h(M(1)) XOR Message(2)
M(3)=h(M(2)) XOR Message(3)
```

(where N is the number of times the key has been used which is passed in clear text.)

That way the bad guys can’t calculate your key sequence ahead of time and decrypt your message before you can.  Also by using a salted hash of the key, the attacker won’t be able to predict the key sequence that will be used next time.

---

I read somewhere:

- The first rule of cryptography is “Cryptography should be left to experts.”
- The second rule is “You are not an expert.”

There is a reason people get PhDs in things like Computer Science and Mathematics.  There is a lot to learn and discover.  Something like this looks fine to me but no doubt it has a gaping hole that an attacker could drive a truck through.

Have fun and don't let grouchy people like me get you down.
/Bob Bryan

Answer (score 3):

If the attacker ever gets to know a plaintext-ciphertext pair, he can calculate the corresponding key.  And from that he can calculate all later keys. i.e. it's trivially vulnerable to a known plain text attack.

Note that when I say that the attacker guesses the message, I don't mean that he's sure that his guess is correct. He might make a few trillion guesses, and if one of them is correct, your whole scheme is broken.

And of course you must not ever reuse a key.

---

A more secure (but twice as slow) algorithm would be:

```
Key(i+1) = h("A"+key)
M(i) = h("B"+key) XOR Message(i)
```

Or a construction similar to CTR mode:

```
M(i) =  h(i+key) XOR Message(i)
```

But I still wouldn't use either.

---

But there is no reason to use such a homebrew algorithm. There are plenty of existing algorithms that work well. For example if you like a stream cipher design, you could use AES in CTR mode.

Comment: i am sure about that attacker can't get plaintext, with this note, what is your aidea?

Comment: @oMiD So you're sure that every single message has a high entropy? That's not a bet I'd like to make. Especially since there is no reason to use a scheme that's vulnerable to known plaintext attacks.